# Azure Application Gateway private ip dns resolution

Tags: azure

Is it possible for the private frontend ip of a V2 Application Gateway to be resolved from the internal vnet dns?

Comment: Custom DNS, or the built in Azure DNS servers?

Comment: Built in ideally but I'm happy to look at other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The private IP address of your App Gateway does not get an automatic DNS label created like the public one does. If you require this you would need to create one in your DNS zone for it. If your using the default Azure DNS servers you won't be able to do this, so you would want to look at switching to something like Azure Private DNS, or hosting your own DNS servers.